# Why do looped describe blocks cause failures?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to use jest to test different implementations of the same thing. The interface is always the same so the tests are always exactly the same, too.

To spare repitition, I tried to put the whole dontMock and describe stuff into a loop like this:

```js
var implementations = [ 'first', 'second', 'third' ]

for(i in implementations) {
  var name = implementations[i],
      path = "../js/components/fancy_" + name

  jest.dontMock(path)
  func = require(path)

  describe(name + " implementation", function() {
    it("does things", function() {
      expect(func()).toBe("one with the world")
    })
  })
}
```

This works, as long as the *implementations* array has only one element. As soon as I add more, failures from from some implementations are shown as failures for others, too. If all implementations are passing, I get green tests.

I also tried to move the *dontMock* part outside in a separate loop, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Possibly a non-closure problem? Maybe try wrapping your `describe` call in a closure so that the callback remembers the value of `func` at the time of passing it

Comment: some suggestions (not solutions)... 1) you're declaring `i` in the loop globally. If any of your other code or dependent libs do the same - things will get very confusing. Put `var` in front of it. 2) don't use a `for..in` loop on an array, use a standard `for` loop, or `.forEach(...)` - as you have it now, there is no way to guarantee the order in which they will be executed - among other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that `describe()` runs asynchronously, rather than your `for .. in` loop. So hopefully, the solution should be to wrap each describe call in an IIFE:

```
var implementations = [ 'first', 'second', 'third' ]

for(i in implementations) {
  var name = implementations[i],
      path = "../js/components/fancy_" + name

  jest.dontMock(path)
  func = require(path)
  (function(func) {
    describe(name + " implementation", function() {
      it("does things", function() {
        expect(func()).toBe("one with the world")
      })
    })
  })(func)
}
```

This does not look very clean and you should probably reorgranize your code someway to avoid that.

Comment: This helps! And thanks to Robbies comment, I tried to simplify it by using forEach instead of for(x in foo) which makes it quite readable again.